# Sort "Tag Summary" alphabetically

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface

After following the [First Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions) link in the "Review Lists (old)" at the bottom of the [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review), I'm presented with a page that has no fewer than 50 tags in a column under a **Tag Summary** heading.

I'd argue that the current way these tags are sorted (by number of associated questions) isn't particularly useful to the majority of users, because most users have a few areas of interest or knowledge, and they seek out tags that are associated with those areas of expertise when answering questions. If a given user has knowledge of `bar`, he/she will seek that tag out, regardless of how many questions are associated with it. By the same token, if the same user has no interest in, or knowledge of, say, `foo`, then the fact that `foo` has the most questions associated with it is irrelevant.

Moreover, since the number of associated questions is dynamic, sorting by the incidence of a tag changes its position in the "Tag Summary" list quite often. Users are then left to scan the list anew each time the number of questions and tags changes.

Why not sort the tags in **Tag Summary** alphabetically?